# Get Changes in Visits from Google Analytics Api

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-data-api

I'm, trying to download some Google Analytics data from their API.
I can download my visitors number.

When you use the Google Analytics webpage you can see a percents of *Changes in visits*, but how do I get that info from their API?

[image: Percents of Visits Changes]

I could try to calculate it by my self, but I have no idea of what algorithm they use.

More info about the API can be found here. [Data Feed Query Explorer](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataExplorer.html)

## edit

```
Final formula
Visits over the last 30 days
StartDate = today.Year, today.Month - 1, today.Day
EndDate = today.Year, today.Month, today.Day - 1


Visits between 31 and 60 days ago
StartDate = today.Year, today.Month - 2, today.Day
EndDate = today.Year, today.Month -1, today.Day - 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614399/using-the-google-analytics-export-api-to-get-a-websites-trend/4615465#4615465),

The formula is pretty simple (excluding today's data):

> (Visits over the last 30 days - Visits between 31 and 60 days ago) /
>   (Visits between 31 and and 60 days ago).

You can see it in action in the interface if you go to the default dashboard, where it shows you the last 30 days, then on the calendar, click "Compare to past" and select the default amount. It'll show you the numbers used for each calculation and the calculations as they appears in that account list.

The API does not, however, expose pre-calculated numbers (for example, they don't compute bounce rate for you; they just give you the pieces for it.)

So, you'd need to do two API requests to get this data. One for `ga:visits` in the last 30 days, and then one for `ga:visits` in the 30 days prior.

Then, when you get it, just subtract, divide, and multiply by 100, and you'll have the percent you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I updated my question, to list, how I calculated my visits numbers, to adjust for changing days in a month.